# How to express 2n as sum of n variables (Java implementation?)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, composition, subset-sum

I wonder if there is an elegant way to derive all [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of 2n as the sum of n non-negative integer variables.

For example, for n = 2 variables x and y, there are 5 compositions with two parts :

x = 0 y = 4; x = 1 y = 3; x = 2 y = 2; x = 3 y = 1; x = 4 y = 0

such that x + y = 4 = 2n.

More generally, the problem can be formulated to find all the compositions of s into n non-negative integer variables with their sum equals to s.

Any suggestion on how to compute this problem efficiently would be welcome, and some pseudo-code would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: while solutions are presented below as in Perl and Prolog, a **Java** implementation may present a new problem as linear data structures such as arrays need to be passed around and manipulated during the recursive calls, and such practice can become quite expensive as n gets larger, I wonder if there is an alternative (and more efficient) **Java** implementation for this problem.

Comment: I take it you mean non-negative integers.

Comment: that's correct. i will edit the question to clarify that

Comment: Do you need to list them, or just count them?

Comment: I don't think the term "permutation" should be used in this case -- it has a different well defined meaning in Combinatorics.

Comment: i would like to list all of them.

Comment: I suggest posting this on http://math.stackexchange.com, this has in itself nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @Darhuuk: It has plenty to do with programming.  The math involved in finding the "permutations" is trivial, but the programming involved to enumerate them all is more involved.  It's an algorithm question.

Comment: @recursive Ok, fair enough :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some python:

```
def sumperms(n, total = None):
   if total == None: 
       # total is the target sum, if not specified, set to 2n
       total = 2 * n

   if n == 1: 
      # if n is 1, then there is only a single permutation
      # return as a tuple.
      # python's syntax for single element tuple is (element,)
      yield (total,)
      return

   # iterate i over 0 ... total
   for i in range(total + 1):
      # recursively call self to solve the subproblem
      for perm in sumperms(n - 1, total - i):
         # append the single element tuple to the "sub-permutation"
         yield (i,) + perm

# run example for n = 3   
for perm in sumperms(3):
   print perm
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 6)
(0, 1, 5)
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 3, 3)
(0, 4, 2)
(0, 5, 1)
(0, 6, 0)
(1, 0, 5)
(1, 1, 4)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 4, 1)
(1, 5, 0)
(2, 0, 4)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 3, 1)
(2, 4, 0)
(3, 0, 3)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 3, 0)
(4, 0, 2)
(4, 1, 1)
(4, 2, 0)
(5, 0, 1)
(5, 1, 0)
(6, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to write this out in pseudo-code, as i barely know Python.

Comment: I attempted to write it in a generally understandable way.  I'll add some comments.

Comment: @skyork: An important detail to remember is that in Python, functions with `yield` in them are *generators*.  They return a function that iterates over all of the times that `yield` was called.  In another language you'd probably want to return arrays, add the current element to them, then concatenate those together.  And you'd get a potentially huge data structure.

Comment: @btilly: hmm, i was trying to implement this in Java, and in order to maintain the results during recursive calls, each call returns a part of the composition (as you suggested), and storing it as an array is kinda expensive considering the number of such arrays and the number of concatenations needed. I wonder if there is an alternative implementation in Java.

Comment: @skyork: http://code.google.com/p/java-yield/ will show you how to translate the Python to more equivalent Java.  Be warned that this will let you start streaming results immediately, but as you will have a lot of results for large n, it will take a long time to stream through them all.

Answer (score 2):

The number of compositions (sums where ordering matters) of 2n into exactly n non-negative parts is the binomial coefficient C(3n-1,n-1).  For example, with n = 2 as above, C(5,1) = 5.

To see this, consider lining up 3n-1 positions.  Choose any subset of n-1 of these, and place "dividers" in those positions.  You then have the remaining blank positions grouped into n groups between dividers (some possibly empty groups where dividers are adjacent).  Thus you have constructed a correspondance of the required compositions with the arrangements of spaces and dividers, and the latter is manifestly counted as combinations of 3n-1 things taken n-1 at a time.

For the purpose of enumerating all the possible compositions we could write a program that actually selects n-1 strictly increasing items s[1],...,s[n-1] from a list [1,...,3n-1].  In accordance with the above, the "parts" would be x[i] = s[i] - s[i-1] - 1 for i = 1,...,n with the convention that s[0] = 0 and s[n] = 3n.

More elegant for the purpose of listing compositions would be to select n-1 weakly increasing items t[1],...,t[n-1] from a list [0,...,2n] and calculate the parts x[i] = t[i] - t[i-1] for i = 1,...,n with the convention t[0] = 0 and t[n] = 2n.

Here's a brief Prolog program that gives the more general listing of compositions of N using P non-negative parts:

```
/* generate all possible ordered sums to N with P nonnegative parts */

composition0(N,P,List) :- 
    length(P,List),
    composition0(N,List).

composition0(N,[N]).
composition0(N,[H|T]) :-
    for(H,0,N),
    M is N - H,
    composition0(M,T).
```

The predicate **compostion0/3** expresses its first argument as the sum of a list of non-negative integers (third argument) having the second argument as its length.

The definition requires a couple of utility predicates that are often provided by an implementation, perhaps in slightly different form.  For completeness a Prolog definition of the counting predicate **for/3** and length of list predicate are as follows:

```
for(H,H,N) :- H =< N.
for(H,I,N) :-
    I < N,
    J is I+1,
    for(H,J,N).

length(P,List) :- length(P,0,List).

length(P,P,[ ]) :- !.
length(P,Q,[_|T]) :-
    R is Q+1,
    length(P,R,T).
```